# Magento2 How to Update product price by website or store id

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, price, stores, magento2.2

I try to programmatically update product price for different website in magento2.

This blow code is working but It will update main website price only, I need to update different website price using different website id.

```
<?php
error_reporting(1);
ini_set('max_execution_time', 0);
$bootstrap = \Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap::create(BP, $_SERVER);
$objectManager = $bootstrap->getObjectManager();
$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
$state = $objectManager->get('\Magento\Framework\App\State');
$state->setAreaCode('frontend');
$product_id = 7878;
$price = "3.99";
$productFactory = $objectManager-
>get('\Magento\Catalog\Model\ProductFactory');
$product = $productFactory->create()->load($product_id);
$product->setPrice($price);
$product->save();
?>
```

How can I load website?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to set store id when you load product object, Your final code look like this

```
$storeId = '1'; //Store ID
$product_id = 7878;
$price = "3.99";
$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
$productFactory = $objectManager->get('\Magento\Catalog\Model\ProductFactory');
$product = $productFactory->create()->setStoreId($storeId)->load($product_id);
$product->setPrice($price);
$product->save();
```

Also, you need to change price scope.

Go to **System->Configuration->Catalog->Catalog Price Scope**

Then in the tab "Price", set price scope to "Website" instead of global.

Comment: @prince any idea about the special price? how we can set it?

Answer (score 3):

Well, That's how I got it working on **Magento 2.2.3+**

```
<?php
namespace Vendor\Module\Helper;

class Product {

    protected $productResourceModel;
    protected $productFactory;

    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product $productResourceModel,
        \Magento\Catalog\Model\ProductFactory $productFactory
    ) {
        $this->productResourceModel = $productResourceModel;
        $this->productFactory = $productFactory;
    }

    public function setPricesPerStore($productId, $storeId, $price, $specialPrice)
    {
        $productFactory = $this->productFactory->create();
        $this->productResourceModel->load($productFactory, $productId);
        $productFactory->setStoreId($storeId);
        $productFactory->setPrice($price);
        $this->productResourceModel->saveAttribute($productFactory, 'price');

        $today = date('Y-m-d', time());
        $nextYear = date('Y-m-d', time() + (60*60*24*7*52));


        if(!$specialPrice || ($price == $specialPrice)) {
            $specialPrice = null;
            $today = null;
            $nextYear = null;
        }

        $productFactory->setSpecialPrice($specialPrice);
        $productFactory->setSpecialFromDate($today);
        $productFactory->setSpecialFromDateIsFormated(true);
        $productFactory->setSpecialToDate($nextYear);
        $productFactory->setSpecialToDateIsFormated(true);

        $this->productResourceModel->saveAttribute($productFactory, 'special_price');
        $this->productResourceModel->saveAttribute($productFactory, 'special_from_date');
        $this->productResourceModel->saveAttribute($productFactory, 'special_to_date');

        return true;
    }
}
```

Comment: how to update the tier price in percentage ?